# Symfony Forms Inject object

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a Symfony Form Type and I want to inject on it another form I have Created:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder();
$form->add('quantity', NumberType::class);
$form->add('options', ProductOptionType::class);
$form->add('notes', TextareaType::class, ]);
```

ProductOptionType is another type I have created but on this type I inject on constructor the current product so I know then what available options this product has in order to add in the form (ie color, size etc).

```
class ProductOptionType extends AbstractType
{    
    private $productOptions;

    public function __construct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->productOptions = $product->getOptions();
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        foreach ($this->productOptions as $option) {
            $builder->add($option->getId(), ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $option->getChoicesForForm(),
                'label' => $option->getName()
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

The Problem is how to pass the constructor here???

```
$form->add('options', ProductOptionType::class);
```

The above throws contstructor none error as it instantiates the type without passign to the injector the product.

Also this one throws exception:

```
$form->add('options', new ProductOptionType($product));
```

Because it expects a string and not an object.

Comment: You need to define your ProductOptionType as a service: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service.  However, you don't generally inject one form type into another since you will need to use the form factory to create the form type type.  It can be done but it's unusual.  A collection, http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html, might be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass extra data with the options

```
class ProductOptionType extends AbstractType
{    

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $productOptions = $options['productOptions'];

        foreach ($productOptions as $option) {
            $builder->add($option->getId(), ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $option->getChoicesForForm(),
                'label' => $option->getName()
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        // you can define a required option field for work
        $resolver->setRequired([
             'productOptions',
         ]);
         // ...
         // You could specify which type of class is supported
        $resolver->setAllowedTypes([
             'productOptions' => ProductOptions:class,
         ]);
    }

}
```

Then use it in the form creation as follow:

```
$form->add('options', ProductOptionType::class, ['productOptions' => $product]);
```

Hope this help

Comment: Yes this is a nice solution thanks! Just for the record from this $form->add('options', ProductOptionType::class, null, ['productOptions' => $product]); remove the null as then it has 4 arguments.